# Remove part of a string after a specific pattern in JAVA

Tags: java, string, comparison, photo

i have this string:

```
http://www.website.com/path/photo.jpg?resize=600%2C400
```

and i want to remove the part after the file type. With other words i want to get

```
http://www.website.com/path/photo.jpg
```

the file type that can exist are .jpg, .png, .gif

any idea how can i implement this?

Comment: Have you tried anything already?

Comment: The best solution would be Regex...

Comment: `"http://www.website.com/path/photo.jpg?resize=600%2C400".split("\\?")[0]`

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve this would be to find the first locaiton of he character `'?'` in your string and then truncate your string till that location.

```
String modifiedUrl = "";
if(url.contains("?"))
{
   modifiedUrl = url.substring(0, url.indexOf("?"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A more URL-specific solution would be to use the logic in the `URL` class, which will be smarter than any regex your can create in the same amount of time.

```
URL fullUrl = new URL("http://www.website.com/path/photo.jpg?resize=600%2C400");
System.out.println(fullUrl.getProtocol() + "://" + fullUrl.getHost()
                   + ":" + fullUrl.getPort() + fullUrl.getPath());
```

You'll want exception handling and null-handling in there to handle cases where bits of the URL aren't provided, like `/localDir/localFile` or `ftp://yourServer.yourDomain/file`.